# Git is not shown in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit

Recently I downloaded EGit to my Eclipse (Luna) but it seems it caused some problems. Because it is not shown under the team bar.

[image]

I couldn't find the reason.

Comment: Can you update your question with how you downloaded/installed it -- maybe the problem lies there, or maybe some configuration change is required.

Comment: I solved the problem. Posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. I guess it is Eclipse Luna specific problem. The solution is start eclipse with `-clean` command.